# Rhythmbox stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, rhythmbox

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu 15, Rhythmbox stopped working.

I open it, or click on some audio file, and it opens but does not play.  It keeps showing "Not Playing" for all kinds of audio files.

I don't think it's a hardware problem, because I'm able to play audio files in other players such as Audacious or even the terminal itself.

Installing all the gstreamer plugins with Synaptic didn't help.

Rhythmbox is the best music player I've ever known and I really wish for it to work again.

Comment: This package has been deleted from xenial.
See here: http://askubuntu.com/a/763973/273285