# cant install rhythmbox in xenial

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.04, rhythmbox

when I try `sudo apt install rhythmbox` I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rhythmbox : Depends: librhythmbox-core9 (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.3.0.0-1~wilyubuntu2 is to be installed
             Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.3.0.0-1~wilyubuntu2 is to be installed
             Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.3.0.0-1~wilyubuntu2 is to be installed
             Recommends: rhythmbox-plugins but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried using `ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox` as a source as well but that responds with this:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I tried making sure I didn't have any weird sources enabled and even deleted anything related to rhythmbox from /etc/apt/sources.list.d
Regular install from Software doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Just did, comes back
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
 Still wont install with same error

Comment: See if `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox` makes a difference (`apt-get` instead of `apt`).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Have tried that too. Returned the exact result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the xenial package has been deleted:
http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox/ubuntu/dists/
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/universe/proposed/rhythmbox

Comment: This user is correct the xenial Rhythmbox package is removed from the repository apparently because this bug:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1545764 was not fixed prior to the xenial deadline.   Rhythmbox was removed from my computer upon upgrade to xenial - Banshee will have to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

The ppa versioned it's rhythmbox packages incorrectly in wily so they are are higher than the rhythmbox packages in xenial.

xenial - 3.3-1ubuntu7

ppa - 3.3.0.0-1~wilyubuntu2

3.3.0.0 is higher than 3.3, to fix just remove all Rb source packages, update sources & install Rb from Ubuntu repos

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I believe Doug is right about the Wily ppa. I purged rhythmbox and all rhythmbox data. I also purged the fossfreedom ppa. Then I found the Rhythmbox deb file for Rhythmbox 3.3-1 (the Xenial version rather than the Wily version) on pkgs.org and was able to install Rhythmbox that way. I can't find a ppa at the moment that has the Xenial version. Hopefully fossfreedom will update his ppa soon.